# how to use keyboard to navigate through li list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have collapsible drop down `ul`. I need to navigate through it using up arrow key and down arrow key !!

This following example is demonstrating collabsible ul li list with input above.
and I have the complete example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MedooEgy/pen/BajYNRE)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// how to navigate to li using up and down arrows in keyboard

  $('#DdlInput').focus(function(){
    $('#mylist').slideDown(200);
  });
  $('#DdlInput').focusout(function(){
    $('#mylist').slideUp(200);
  });
  
$('#DdlInput').on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#mylist li").filter(function() {     $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#mylist {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;   
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
#mylist li{
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top:7px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="DdlInput" type="text"/>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Base</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @hev1 using keyboard ... using up arrow and down arrow keys on the keyboard using jquery.

Comment: @hev1 to navigate through li and when I press enter the li value appears into the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think this is the solution to your problem:**

```js
$('#DdlInput').focus(function () {
    $('#mylist').slideDown(200);
});
$('#DdlInput').focusout(function () {
    $('#mylist').slideUp(200);
});

var li = $('li');
var liSelected;

$("#DdlInput").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }

        console.log(liSelected[0].innerText);
        $("#DdlInput").val(liSelected[0].innerText);

    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }

        console.log(liSelected[0].innerText);

        $("#DdlInput").val(liSelected[0].innerText);
    }
});
```

```css
#mylist {
    display: none;
}

li.selected {
    background: grey;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="DdlInput" type="text" />
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Base</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **`Note: I didn't add any mouse click event here.`**

Comment: that's it but it loses the functionality of query filter which allows user to filter the list by typing in the input

Comment: Bro, I've just implemented the keyboard arrow event here. Nothing else, if you need the filter, you can add this as well into it.